# MYSQL Syntax Error

Tags: magento-1.9, database

On Magento 1.9.2.4 I'm using a plugin wich pulls ekomi ratings.

On some articles I throws follwoing exception:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')) AND (`state` = '1') ORDER BY time DESC' at line 1, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `meecom_ekomi_rating_cache` AS `main_table` WHERE (()) AND (`state` = '1') ORDER BY time DESC

I've no idea what this means. Is there an easy fix for that?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the plugin has a flaw in the code, specifically in the `where` statement.

Most likely the issue will be in a resource model. I'd suggest going to your: `document_root/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php` file and changing `$_debug`, `$_logAllQueries`, and `$_logCallStack` to true.

Once you've done that, and you re-run the application, you'll now see a log file generated in `protected $_debugFile = 'var/debug/pdo_mysql.log';`. Note that this is "loud" so it will log *ALL* sql queries....I'd suggest getting to the page where you know the error is being generated, and delete everything in the `pdo_mysql.log` file, then perform the necessary actions to generate the error.

You'll want to investigate the call stack to see what is causing the `where` clause to be empty...and then you'll want to modify the code appropriately.

I hope that helps...as I can't give you a specific answer without seeing the plugin code (as I haven't used that one before).